# How to test a simple data object class which implements NSCoding?

Tags: ios, unit-testing, xctest

I have a small data object that needs to be serialized and deserialized. Lets say it is called `WeatherDetails`, and it looks like this:

**WeatherDetails.h**

```
@interface WeatherDetails : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
@private

@protected
}

#pragma mark - Properties

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *weatherCode;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *weatherDescription;

@end
```

**WeatherDetails.m**

```
#import "WeatherDetails.h"

@implementation WeatherDetails

NSString *const WEATHER_DETAILS_WEATHER_CODE_KEY = @"s";
NSString *const WEATHER_DETAILS_WEATHER_DESCRIPTION_KEY = @"sT";

#pragma mark - Initialization, NSCoding and Dealloc

- (instancetype)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder
{
    self = [super init];

    _weatherCode = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"weatherCode"];
    _weatherDescription = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:@"weatherDescription"];

    return self;
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder
{
    [aCoder encodeObject:_weatherCode forKey:@"weatherCode"];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_weatherDescription forKey:@"weatherDescription"];
}
```

Currently my tests look like this;

```
#import <XCTest/XCTest.h>
#import <OCMock/OCMock.h>
#import "WeatherDetails.h"
@interface WeatherDetailsTests : XCTestCase

@end

@implementation WeatherDetailsTests

- (void)testThatWeatherCodeIsEncoded
{
    WeatherDetails *details = [[WeatherDetails alloc] init];
    [details setWeatherCode:@"A"];

    NSData *archive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:details];

    WeatherDetails *unarchive = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archive];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"A", [unarchive weatherCode]);
}

- (void)testThatWeatherDescriptionIsEncoded
{
    WeatherDetails *details = [[WeatherDetails alloc] init];
    [details setWeatherDescription:@"A"];

    NSData *archive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:details];

    WeatherDetails *unarchive = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archive];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects(@"A", [unarchive weatherDescription]);
}
```

I have a gut feeling that this approach to testing if all properties are correctly encoded is not really optimal as there is duplication, but I can't really think of a better approach. Does anyone have a tip for me on improving this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I improved it by applying a [custom assertion](http://xunitpatterns.com/Custom%20Assertion.html);

> When To Use It
>
> We should consider creating a Custom Assertion whenever any of the following are true:
>
> - **We find ourselves writing (or cloning) the same assertion logic in test after test**
> - We find ourselves writing Conditional Test Logic in the result verification part of our tests. That is, our calls to Assertion Methods are embedded in if statements or loops.
> - The result verification parts of our tests are suffering from Obscure Test  because we are using procedural rather than declarative result verification in the tests.
> - We find ourselves doing Frequent Debugging whenever assertions fail because they do not provide enough information.

The custom assertion currently looks like this:

```
/*!
 * @define XCTAssertEqualSerialized(value, object, selector)
 * Serializes (\a object), then desirializes it and compares result's property (\a propertyName) to (\a value) with XCTAssertEqualObjects
 * @param value Value to compare.
 * @param object Object to serialize.
 * @param selector Objects property to compare.
 */

#define XCTAssertEqualSerialized(value, object, selector) \
({ \
NSData *archived = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object]; \
NSObject *unarchived = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archived]; \
XCTAssertEqualObjects(value, [unarchived valueForKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(selector)]); \
})

/*!
 * @define XCTAssertNotNilSerialized(object, selector)
 * Serializes (\a object), then desirializes it and checks result's property (\a propertyName) is not nil with XCTAssertNotNil
 * @param object Object to serialize.
 * @param selector Objects property to compare.
 */

#define XCTAssertNotNilSerialized(object, selector) \
({ \
NSData *archived = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:object]; \
NSObject *unarchived = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archived]; \
XCTAssertNotNil([unarchived valueForKeyPath:NSStringFromSelector(selector)]); \
})
```

Which results in the tests looking like this:

```
- (void)testThatWeatherCodeIsEncoded
{
    WeatherDetails *details = [[WeatherDetails alloc] init];
    [details setWeatherCode:@"A"];

    XCTAssertEqualSerialized(@"A", details, @selector(weatherCode));
}

- (void)testThatWeatherDescriptionIsEncoded
{
    WeatherDetails *details = [[WeatherDetails alloc] init];
    [details setWeatherDescription:@"A"];

    XCTAssertEqualSerialized(@"A", details, @selector(weatherDescription));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

What you really want to test is that the object is same before and after you archive it.

Implement a method in your `WeatherDetails` to compare the objects (or override `isEqual:`).

```
- (BOOL)isEqualToWeatherDetails:(WeatherDetails *)details
{
    if (![details isKindOfClass:[WeatherDetails class]]) return NO;
    return [self.weatherCode == details.weatherCode && self.weatherDescription isEqualToString:details.weatherDescription];
}
```

Then you can do all your equality comparisons at once:

```
- (void)testNSCoder
{
    WeatherDetails *details = [[WeatherDetails alloc] init];
    [details setWeatherCode:@"A"];
    details.weatherDescription = @"Cloudy";

    NSData *archive = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:details];

    WeatherDetails *unarchive = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:archive];

    XCTAssertTrue([details isEqualToWeatherDetails:unarchive]);
}
```

If you overrode `isEqual:` then you could compare doing this:

```
XCTAssertEqualObjects(details, unarchive);
```

Apple tends to add additional methods (`isEqualToArray:`, `isEqualToDictionary:`). `isEqual:` is used by collections like NSSet and NSDictionary

Comment: This was my initial thought as well. I guess the thing to consider is how fast you would be wanting to be able to find the exact point of failure; in this particular case it would probably not be much harder to find this exact point of failure in your proposed solution than in the case of testing each property for serialisation individually, so your proposed solution is a valid one.